# Error "No matching client found for package name 'io.invertase.firebase'" when executing "react-native run-android"

Tags: android, firebase, react-native

I followed the instructions in [Add Firebase to your Android project](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup#add_firebase_to_your_app) to configure my (ejected) react-native project.
When I execute either

> react-native run-android

or I build the project in Android Studio, I get the error:

> Task :react-native-firebase:processDebugGoogleServices FAILED
>   Parsing json file: /Users/.../myapp/node_modules/react-native-firebase/android/google-services.json

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':react-native-firebase:processDebugGoogleServices'.

  > No matching client found for package name 'io.invertase.firebase'

This is my addition to the project *build.gradle*:

```
dependencies {
  implementation project(':react-native-firebase')
  implementation project(':react-native-image-crop-picker')
  implementation project(':react-native-vector-icons')
  implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
  implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${rootProject.ext.supportLibVersion}"
  implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
  implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:16.0.1"
  implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.4"
  implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:17.1.1'
  implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.4'
}
...
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

and this is the app *build.gradle*:

```
buildscript {
  ext {
    buildToolsVersion = "28.0.2"
    minSdkVersion = 16
    compileSdkVersion = 27
    targetSdkVersion = 26
    supportLibVersion = "27.1.1"
  }
  repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
  }
}

allprojects {
  repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    google()
    jcenter()
    maven {
      // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) 
      // is installed   from npm
        url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
    }
    maven {
        url "https://jitpack.io"
    }
  }
}
```

I also updated the versions in *.../myapp/node_modules/react-native-firebase/android/build.gradle* to:

```
dependencies {
  // compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
  api "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
  api "com.android.support:support-v4:$supportVersion"

  // Firebase SDKs
  compileOnly('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.3@aar') {
    transitive = true
  }

  //noinspection GradleCompatible
  compileOnly "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.4"
  compileOnly "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:16.0.1"
  compileOnly "com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:16.0.1"
  compileOnly "com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.4"
  compileOnly "com.google.firebase:firebase-config:16.0.1"
  compileOnly "com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:16.2.1"
  compileOnly "com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.3"
  compileOnly "com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:17.1.1"
  compileOnly "com.google.firebase:firebase-functions:16.1.1"
  compileOnly "com.google.firebase:firebase-invites:16.0.4"
  compileOnly "com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.3"
  compileOnly "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.3"
  compileOnly "com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:16.1.2"
  compileOnly 'me.leolin:ShortcutBadger:1.1.21@aar'
  implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:17.1.1'
  implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.4'
}
```

Ih I used Tools->Firebase in Android Studio and use **Connect to Firebase** and **Add Firebase authentication to your app** (or Add Firebase firestorm...) buttons, then it adds different versions for these libraries as in:

```
// implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:17.1.1'
// implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.4'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:17.0.1:15.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.1:15.0.0'
```

(I commented out my original entries in both the project and react-native-firebase build.gradle files). But still the same error.

Any suggestions?
Thanks!